# Finding the second greatest value in a row in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How does one find the second greatest value of each row (specific columns) of a MySQL table?
For eg, I have a table like the following,

```
| Game_no | Player_1 | Player_2 | Player_3|
|:--------|:---------|:---------|:--------|
| 1       | 2030     | NULL     | 120     |
| 2       | 1500     | 720      | NULL    |
```

I expect a result as,

```
| Game_no | Second_place_score|
|:--------|:------------------|
| 1       | 120               |
| 2       | 720               |
```

Null values exist, but there are no duplicates in the table.

Note that this only a representation, and in the original table, more than 2 (4, to be precise) players may have non-NULL values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might do:

```
  SELECT
    x.*,
    GREATEST(
      CASE WHEN x.Player_1 < x.topscore THEN x.Player_1 ELSE -1 END,
      CASE WHEN x.Player_2 < x.topscore THEN x.Player_2 ELSE -1 END,
      CASE WHEN x.Player_3 < x.topscore THEN x.Player_3 ELSE -1 END
    ) as secondhighest
      

  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      t.*,
      GREATEST(
        COALESCE(Player_1, -1),
        COALESCE(Player_2, -1),
        COALESCE(Player_3, -1)
      ) as topscore
    FROM
      t
  ) x
```

We use the GREATEST function to find the top score, then use it to hide the top score in another round of assessments of the scores. GREATEST will report null if any argument is null, so we swap nulls out for -1. Once we have the top score we can assess each score against it and only retain scores that are less than top, and pass them through greatest again to get the second greatest

Comment: Thanks, but could you clarify what x.* and t.* are?

Comment: `t` is your table (you never said what its name was). `x` is the alias given to the subquery that does the first calc of the greatest score. It's wise to give all subqueries an alias because no database complains if you do but some databases complain if you don't ;)

Comment: Oh, alright, thanks. Got it mixed up at first.

Answer (score 0):

One way to find the second greatest value is to sum all 3 columns and subtract the greatest and the least value:

```
SELECT Game_no,
       COALESCE(Player_1, 0) + COALESCE(Player_2, 0) + COALESCE(Player_3, 0) -
       GREATEST(COALESCE(Player_1, 0), COALESCE(Player_2, 0), COALESCE(Player_3, 0)) - 
       LEAST(COALESCE(Player_1, 0), COALESCE(Player_2, 0), COALESCE(Player_3, 0)) Second_place_score 
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d0e6aa0957491df172c4b552cb0ec1a8).
Results:

| Game_no | Second_place_score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 |
| 2 | 720 |

Comment: It works well for games where two players have non-Null value, but for games where three or more players play, it doesn't work as well. I'll edit my question to make it a little clearer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor this answer is about the question as you posted it. If your requirement is different then you can post a new question.

Comment: Sorry about that. Am new to this community, so still a little unclear about the rules